# Cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<business.clspluginsprp>' to 'business.clspluginsprp

Tags: c#, .net

I was trying to display the data in Grid View int he following manner  but I am getting this error.

```
List<business.clspluginsprp> objprp = new List<business.clspluginsprp>();
business.clsplugins obj = new business.clsplugins();

for (Int32 i = 0; i < k.Length; i++)
{

    Int32 z = Convert.ToInt32(k.GetValue(i));
    objprp.Add(obj.fnd_plugins(z));

}

GridView2.DataSource = objprp;
GridView2.DataBind();
```

I am really not a pro in ASP.NET. Please help in resolving this error. 
Edit--
Full code of the event http://pastebin.com/pX2mNRna

Comment: On what line do you get this error?

Comment: Why are you never using the `obj` variable?

Comment: @Jon He is using it `objprp.Add(obj.fnd_plugins(z));`

Comment: K here is an array. Here's the full code: http://pastebin.com/pX2mNRna

Comment: @Elalfer: Whoops - missed that.

Comment: @Cipher: `var list=new List<>()` - yeah, that's not going to work...

Comment: Can I suggest someone edit the question and move the content of that pastebin into the question?  So that future generations of programmers can see this and understand the issue and the answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would guess your fnd_plugins method returns a List in stead of a single object.
You can use addRange on the objprp to add a list.

Comment: @Cipher: In what way is that the full code? In particular, it doesn't say anything about the `fnd_plugins` method signature.

Comment: Wait.  the code in pastebin is different from the code in the question.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Sorry, have a look at the fnd_plugins method here: http://pastebin.com/rcZF00PE

Comment: @Cipher: Lo and behold, we find that Karel's guess is accurate. There is a *lot* wrong with this code though, both in terms of style and correctness.

Comment: Line 32 is different -   objprp = obj.fnd_plugins(z);